# Creating div element dynamically using javascript not supporting while changing the screen resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

im adding a image inside the div at mouse clicked position by getting the X and Y coordinates of div. its working well and the image is added at the mouse clicked position. but when I try to change the **screen resolution**, **images are moved some where they are not in the div**. I need to design this screen to support all screen resolution(for mobile and surface also). can anyone help me on this. thanks in advance.

here is my working code:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function mouseclicked(event) {
    var img = document.createElement('img')
    img.src = "Printers/printer2.jpg";
    img.width = '50';
    img.height = '50';
    img.style.position = "absolute";
    img.style.left = event.pageX + "px";
    img.style.top = event.pageY + "px";
    $('#maindiv').append(img);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your code before appending img to maindiv (mydiv being your maindiv element):

```
var divPos = mydiv.getBoundingClientRect ();
     img.style.position = "relative";
     img.style.left = divPos.left + (event.pageX - divPos.left) + "px";
     img.style.top = divPos.top + (event.pageY - divPos.top)  + "px";
```

Comment: thanks daksh, I tried with your code, its supports screen resolution. but my image is not added at the position where i clicked. it is added at some distance from mouse clicked position. can u pls help me on this. thanks u.